# How to convert object structure nodeJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

i have an object with n members like this :

```
 {
  open: '122.31000000',
  high: '137.50000000',
  low: '119.50000000',
  close: '135.92000000',
  volume: '1436796.12449000',
  closeTime: 1585007999999,
} 
{
  open: '132.63000000',
  high: '137.13000000',
  low: '121.10000000',
  close: '122.32000000',
  volume: '1055699.86532000',
  closeTime: 1584921599999,
}
```

I want to convert this object like this without using any for loop, how can i do this?

```
{  
  o: '122.31000000',
  h: '137.50000000',
  l: '119.50000000',
  c: '135.92000000',
  v: '1436796.12449000',
  d: 1585007999999
},
{
  o: '132.63000000',
  h: '137.13000000',
  l: '121.10000000',
  c: '122.32000000',
  v: '1055699.86532000'
  d: '1584921599999'
}
```

Comment: Is there any pattern you are following for renaming the object keys? I did not understand using d for closeTime? can you explain that?

Comment: Why would you want to avoid a loop? Do you know how to do it *with* a loop? If yes, please post the code that you would use for that, so that we can suggest an equivalent alternative.

Comment: @Bergi _"without using any **`for`** loop"_ ;)

Comment: yes i konw how to do with for loop i can assign one of one values with for loop but code performance is decreasing

Comment: this is japanse candle pattern and i give data from binance api

Comment: How can using a single loop `(O(n))` will decrease your code performance? Would you please explain?

Comment: You couldn't achive what you want without loop.(map, forEach, for ...etc). Actually, you want to change a bulk of objects , not single one.

Comment: I've used the Binance API before, it does not return Objects with keys. It returns an [Array of Arrays](https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=ETHBTC&interval=1m). What library on top of the API are you using? Because that library is certainly looping over the results to produce that, so if you want to increase performance, that's where you need to act.

Comment: @blex Same for `for` loops specifically. Especially if the OP doesn't know how to do that, it is the first thing they should try.

Comment: @FardinNoruzi Please post the code you have for that. I doubt that "performance is decreasing" because of your for loop. There is no way to avoid the looping over the data structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are going to have to use some sort of loop. One option is you can use map with destructuring.

```js
 const data = [{
  open: '122.31000000',
  high: '137.50000000',
  low: '119.50000000',
  close: '135.92000000',
  volume: '1436796.12449000',
  closeTime: 1585007999999,
},
{
  open: '132.63000000',
  high: '137.13000000',
  low: '121.10000000',
  close: '122.32000000',
  volume: '1055699.86532000',
  closeTime: 1584921599999,
}]

const updated = data.map(({open: o, high: h, low: l, close: c, volume: v, closeTime: d}) => ({o, h, l, c, v, d}))

console.log(updated)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to transform into your expected result.

```js
const data = [{ open: '122.31000000', high: '137.50000000', low: '119.50000000', close: '135.92000000', volume: '1436796.12449000', closeTime: 1585007999999, }, { open: '132.63000000', high: '137.13000000', low: '121.10000000', close: '122.32000000', volume: '1055699.86532000', closeTime: 1584921599999, }];

const result = data.map(e => 
  Object.keys(e).reduce((a, c) => {
    if (c === 'closeTime') a['d'] = e[c];
    else a[c[0]] = e[c];
    return a;
  }, {})
);

console.log(result);
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with for loops, but you can do this with other techniques. Note that this will not improve performance at all, since you're still technically looping through each item and building a new object for each one.

```js
const propertyRenaming = {
  open: 'o',
  high: 'h',
  low: 'l',
  close: 'c',
  volume: 'v',
  closeTime: 'd'
};

const transformed = data.map(obj => 
  Object.entries(data).reduce((result, [prop, value]) => 
    Object.assign(result, { [propertyRenaming[prop]]: value }), 
    {}
  )
);
```